# go-wkhtmltopdf cannot show image

Tags: html, go, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf v1.6.1`. I want to create simple biodata with HTML file. I try to add floating image (profile picture) at right corner, but the image is not showing

This is my sample test.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="padding: 50px; text-align: justify;">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Biodata</h1>
    <br>
    <div style="float: right; margin-bottom: 30px;">
      <img src="../image/profile_pic.jpeg" height="150px">
    </div>
    <div>
    <strong>Name:</strong> John
    </div>
    <br>
    <strong>Birth date:</strong> 2001-01-01
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>Birth place:</strong> Unknown
    <br>
    <br>
    <Strong>Sex:</Strong> Male/Female
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>Height:</strong> 200 cm
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>Hobby:</strong> Sleeping
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Go code

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "strings"

    gopdf "github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf"
)

func init() {
    htmlTmp, err := template.ParseFiles("files/html/test.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err = htmlTmp.Execute(buf, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    pdfGen, err := gopdf.NewPDFGenerator()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    pageReader := gopdf.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(buf.String()))
    pageReader.PageOptions.EnableLocalFileAccess.Set(true)
    pdfGen.AddPage(pageReader)
    if err := pdfGen.Create(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    if err := pdfGen.WriteFile("files/generated/test.pdf"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like when I run the code: [test_from_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uW90.png)

I already use the option to enable local file access, but the image is still not showing. Instead, there is a block at where the image should be showing

Expected behavior
I try to use wkhtmltopdf from terminal to see the differences

`wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access files/html/test.html files/generated/test.pdf`

This is the result: [test_from_terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xulk1.png)

It shows the image where I want them to be

What should I do to get the expected result from code?

Comment: It probablt did not resolve appropriately the file path ../image/profile_pic.jpeg have you made it relative to the HTML or the working directory of your program ? Internally this lib uses the binary so there should be no problem, see https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/wkhtmltopdf.go#L167

Comment: or, it might just that https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/issues/28

Comment: yes, it is the same issue with [github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/issues/28](https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/issues/28). I will just do what is suggested there for the time being, until proper wrapper is available

Answer (score 0):

Same issue can be found in [github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/issues/28](https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/issues/28). The library author is still working on it, so for the time being we can follow what to do from the link.